# React (Native) Architecture and state management

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux

Trying to understand the best practice for React/React Native state. Coming from the Java world, I tend to follow MVC/MVVM in my applications, but reading about other approaches makes me wonder if I am designing my application properly.

**Premise:**

- App mostly for consuming video and audio content, storing user statistics and progress
- *React Native Firebase* from invertase.io
- *Redux* used for storing data structure from *Firebase Realtime Database*

My current approach:

- If a React Component needs data, it gets it via Redux or parent component via props.
- If a component needs to manipulate/fetch more data, I have separate viewmodel classes (Typescript files with no dependency to React/RN) that are accessed in a component.
- If the viewmodel gets new data from somewhere, the component state gets it via Observer pattern by implementing an interface
- If data needs to be persisted to Redux and/or Firebase, the viewmodel does it. I pass the Store object from the component

Approach I read/heard/discussed:

- All data from/to components is received/sent through Redux
- All data manipulations are done in Redux Actions
- No separate controllers/viewmodels

I don't have too much history with React Native, so I am trying to understand whether the latter approach is actually superior for some reason.

Comment: First off, react isn't an MVC framework.  If you want to learn react, great, but you'll need to toss out MVC.  Secondly, I wouldn't start out with Redux out of the gate, especially if just learning react.  You can most likely get away with component level state management and passing state to children via props if need be.

Comment: I'm not just learning React, I am developing an app for a client, and I definitely need Redux. The question is whether I am structuring the data flow properly.

Answer (score 2):

[These](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i__969noyAM) [talks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYkdrAPrdcw) helped me understand Flux at a fundamental level. The basic idea is **unidirectional data flow.** Watch the talks and pay attention to them.

You don't need Redux to implement Flux– I used Alt.js instead.

Comment: That's a good hint, thank you, but not exactly an answer to the question.